# Why will vue draggable items not move between lists?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuedraggable, vue.draggable

I am trying to create a card builder using Vue draggable. I have a row full of `cardElements` and these can be dragged to the card builder. The card builder is a rectangle made up of individual "buckets" of lists. Here is what it looks like:

[Card builder Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGoNU.jpg)

Here is the `script` to generate the elements list:

```js
import draggable from 'vuedraggable'

export default {
    name: "clone",
    display: "Clone",
    order: 2,
    components: {
        draggable
    },

    data() {
        return {
            cardElements: [
                { name: "Logo", id: 1 },
                { name: "Stamp", id: 2 }
            ],
            arrA: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        log: function(evt) {
            window.console.log(evt);
        }
    }
};
```

You can see that the `cardElements` are correctly rendered from script and this is how they are rendered in the HTML:

```html
<draggable class="dragArea list-group" :list="cardElements" :group="{ name: 'people', pull: 'clone', put: false }" @change="log">
    <div class="list-group-item" v-for="element in cardElements" :key="element.name">
        {{ element.name }}
    </div>
</draggable>
```

These are draggable and I can change their order like so:

[Changed Order of items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eul4.jpg)

Each "bucket" on the card is declared as an array like so (this is only for the top left space on the card builder, each square is a different number):

```js
data() {
    return {
        cardElements: [
            { name: "Logo", id: 1 },
            { name: "Stamp", id: 2 }
        ],
        arrA: []
    };
}
```

```html
<draggable class="dragArea list-group" :list="arrA" group="cardItem" @change="log">
    <div class="lvl1-1 bucket empty" v-for="element in arrA" :key="element.name">
        {{ element.name }}
    </div>
</draggable>
```

But when I drag an element from the `cardElements` list to the `arrA` list, it doesn't move and I'm not sure why. I can get it working in the example code supplied [here](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/example/components/clone.vue), but not when I change it to my own code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had the group defined as `:group="{ name: 'people',` and then was calling it as `group="cardItem"` so I changed `:group="{ name: 'people',` to this `:group="{ name: 'cardItem',` and it worked